# Web scraper software for dynamic pages

Tags: html, web-scraping

I'm doing some SEO work for a friend and before I begin, want to do a proper inventory of his site. However, much of his site is dynamic - the content is drawn from data initiated by URL parameters, and the html doesn't render the data until the page has loaded. This means that conventional scrapers, such as Httrack, don't pick up on the bulk of the page content.

There are dozens - possibly even hundreds - of pages (due to the number of permutations from the URL parameters).

Can anyone think of a tool that I can use to go through each of these and get the actual html of a rendered page

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

Comment: Sorry, I should have considered this.